# Django set last_online middleware not working

Tags: django

I want to log the last time my user has accessed the website and have implemented this middleware. It however does not store the most updated time.

middleware.py

```
class LastOnlineMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            request.user.profile.last_online = timezone.now()
            request.user.profile.save()
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_online = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dose not work because `process_request` is not called in `__call__` function.

You should change `__call__` function like below.

```
def __call__(self, request):
    self.process_request(request)
    return self.get_response(request)
```

or to make `LastOnlineMiddleware` subclass of `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin`.

If you use MiddlewareMixin, there is no need to define `__init__` and `__call__` function. You just needed to define `process_request` function written in the question.